# Global Maximums and Minimums

Tags: optimization

My book states:

"It is also true that if $x^*$ is an interior point and:

- a global maximum of $f$ , then $d^2f(x^*)$ is negative semi-definite.
- a global minimum of $f$ , then $d^2f(x^*)$ is positive semi-definite.

But, it is not true that if $x^*$ is a critical point and $d^2f(x^*)$ is negative
(positive) semidefinite, then $x^*$ is a local maximum (minimum).

However consider the function: $x^4+x^2-6xy+3y^2$ .

It has a global minimum on $(x,y)=(1,1)$ and $(x,y)=(-1,-1)$ .

However the Hessian at this points, does not seem to be semi-definite.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what do you think is the matrix of second partial derivatives of your function?

Comment: I see your deleted second "answer." Yes, a definite hessian is also semi-definite.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is the Hessian ...

Which shall be equal to:

\begin{matrix}
  12x^2 +2 & -6 \\
  -6 & 6 & 
  .
 \end{matrix}

Which is positive definite for the solution at hand, right?

Comment: yes, positive definite at $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ which are local (and global) minima, and indefinite at $(0,0)$ which is a saddle point. Maybe your trouble is the prefix "semi." The word semidefinite **includes** definite.

Comment: Willt, thanks for your help. So a definite hessian is also semi definite?